# Regex: Password validation of php

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on some password validation on my new project. I have this rules that i want to convert on regex pattern using php preg_match() function:

- Accept all characters.
- Except spaces.
- With minimum of 4 chars.
- Max 20 chars.

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: See [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/48346033#48346033)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this**

```
(?s)^(\S{4,20})$
```

**Explanation**

```
"(?s)" +     // Match the remainder of the regex with the options: dot matches newline (s)
"^" +        // Assert position at the beginning of the string
"(" +        // Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   "\\S" +       // Match a single character that is a “non-whitespace character”
      "{4,20}" +      // Between 4 and 20 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
")" +
"$"          // Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. The only requirement in this statement is a minimum of 4 and a maximum of 20 of any of your "allowed" characters.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\W][\S]{4,20}$/
```

If you would like to require at least one of each type:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)[0-9A-Za-z\W][^\s]{4,20}$/
```

The second option **explained**:

```
//Look ahead for a lower case
(?=.*[a-z])

//Look ahead for an uppercase
(?=.*[A-Z])

//Look ahead for a number
(?=.*\d)

//Look ahead for a non-word character
(?=.*\W)

//Specify allowed characters (not space), minimum of 4, and maximum of 20 chars
[0-9A-Za-z\W][^\s]{4,20}
```